# How to change the font of part of an expression with GREP?

Tags: adobe-indesign, grep

I have the below expression and I want to just change the lowercase *i* to a different font and leave *HMI* as is. But I want to do this throughout the document no matter the text size or color.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Search for every character `i` followed `(?=)` by `HMI` and change it for a different font:

```
i(?=HMI)
```

[image]

Comment: Man, you are fast. Beat me by a few seconds.  :-)